# Taiwanese Mandarin vs Mainland Mandarin

Tags: mandarin, usage, reference-materials

A reference request.

Is there any good source  of the differences word choice/meaning between Taiwan and Mainland Chinese?

Not asking about Chinese Characters, but usage.

Spain have different word choice or even different words for the same thing, than in Mexico for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [An article on Chinese Government Official Website](http://www.gov.cn/jrzg/2012-08/13/content_2203236.htm)

The differences of word usage may be explained like:

> “机车”在大陆一般指“用来牵引列车车厢的动力车，即火车头”，在台湾则指摩托车

To translate in English, "机车" in Mandarin means locomotive, while "机车" in Taiwan means motorcycle.

one can buy a paper-based dictionary at amazon dot cn.

[image: 两岸常用词典]
[image: 两岸现代汉语常用词典]

I am not sure I can post urls to a commercial site, so please perform a search by yourself on amazon dot cn with keyword: 两岸常用词典. The search had returned at least 3 results for me on 2012/09/26.

And according to the article:

> 据悉，《两岸常用词典》网络版已于２月在两岸共建的“中华语文知识库”网站上开通

one can also [access Taiwan-version dictionary online](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/clk/index.php) or [Mandarin-version dictionary online](http://www.zhonghuayuwen.org/dictquery.aspx?i=15526)
now. :)

If you try to look for "硬碟(Taiwan Usage)", it will also show you "硬盘/硬磁盘(Mandarin Usage)".

[Please try it for yourself!](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/clk/index.php/search/%E7%A1%AC%E7%A2%9F)

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a pretty thorough overview of the differences: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwanese_Mandarin